# passing in and out parameter to a mysql stored procedure and return the out parameter in the nodejs code

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CountOrderByStatus`(
        IN orderStatus VARCHAR(50),
        OUT total INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT count(orderNumber)
    INTO total
    FROM orders
    WHERE status = orderStatus;
END
```

This is my stored procedure.  I just want to get the out parameter `total`'s value in my nodejs application

Comment: We will need to see the code you have in your nodejs app that tries to read this value.  That way, we can point out any errors

Answer (score 1):

```
db_ask.query(("SET @a = 0; CALL CountOrderByStatus('" + _orderStatus + "', @a); SELECT @a;"),function(err, results){


//process result


});
```

Assuming that db_ask is your connection to mysql db .

Have a nice day,
Alex.

Comment: Is this safe for concurrent with pool in which session variables keep live until the session ends?